# How to manage jade templates for server and client side with express?

Tags: express, pug

Suppose I'm putting together an application for comparing pizza shops. 
I have a template for my list of pizza shops that looks like this:

```
table
    tr
        th Rank
        th Name
        th Date Ordered
        th Address
        each shop in shops
            tr 
                td= shop.rank
                td= shop.name
                td= shop.dateOrdered
                td
                    each line in shop.address
                        span #{line} <br/>
```

And the layout for each page should look like this:

```
doctype 5
html
    head
        title Pizza Wars
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/style/style.css')
    body
        #wrapper
            h1.main-title.section.group Pizza Wars
            div.section.group
                include side-menu
                block content
```

When a user requests the page at '/shops' I want to respond with the full html of the page. When a user is already at '/' and they navigate in-page to '/shops', I want to request just the JSON, and render the template client side (I'm using backbone.js, if that's of any interest).

Since Express no longer supports layouts, I suspect I'll have to `extend` layout.jade in my shops.jade file, but the problem with doing this is that my shops.jade file would render the html for the entire page, and thus be useless client-side, where I only want it to render the table of shops.

Another option I've considered is having two calls to res.render in my server code, one to render the shops list, and one to render the layout with that list as the content. That solution is obviously sub-optimal.

Has anyone seen/found a way to use jade to cater to both of these situations?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm using is to send no markup inside the body when the page loads, and include with that response the json data for whatever page the client is viewing. Then I let backbone handle rendering the html. This seems to be common in backbone apps.